# Trouble adding a caption below thumbnail in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I have a thumbnail image I've built using Bootstrap 3 (metro bootstraps, to be specific - https://talkslab.github.io/metro-bootstrap/components.html)

All works as expected, but the issue I'm having is making a caption under the thumbnail, i.e. a div with text.  I want the caption to be fixed under the thumbnail even if window is resized.  This is what I've tried:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium tile-purple col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="fa-links">
                
                <div class='gun-icon-container'>
               <img src = "img/handcuffs.png" alt="BJIA-image" class="gun-icon" style='vertical-align:center;width:80px;'>
             </div>
                </a>
      </div>
      <div class ="caption" style='text-align:left;margin-top: 60%;'>
              This is my caption
      </div>
</div>
```

There's two issues.  1) even using text-align, I can't get the text to stop floating to the right. 2) on window resize, the caption floats above the thumbnail instead of remaining under it.

Photos of what the thumbnail currently looks like:

[image]

[image]